handset can't connect with bluetooth, shows connection fail
I am using Ubuntu 22.04. My headset was running fine. Two days ago I installed pulse and restart the PC. Afterwards my headset connected but today when I started my PC and try to connect the headset with Bluetooth it fails. In terminal using bluetoothctl control it shows connection fail.
Latitude-5491:~$ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# devices
Device 74:45:CE:A1:19:21 WH-CH510
[bluetooth]# connect 74:45:CE:A1:19:21
Attempting to connect to 74:45:CE:A1:19:21
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed br-connection-profile-unavailable

Can any one help me to connect this device
